How to copy item with Referrers and References in Sitecore Razl?
We need to copy the particular page item from one site to another site along with templates, images, renderings and data source items used for that item.
How to copy item with Referrers and References in Sitecore Razl?

You can use Razl Powershell Cmdlets to copy the referenced items, for the page item in Sitecore from source to target url. Below is the snippet that can be used for the same.
# Source Connection
$sourceConnection = Get-RazlConnection -SitecoreWebUrl {{SourceUrl}} -DatabaseName master -AccessGuid "00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444" -Name "Source Sitecore"
# Target Connection
$targetConnection = Get-RazlConnection -SitecoreWebUrl {{TargetUrl}} -DatabaseName master -AccessGuid "00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444" -Name "Target Sitecore"
# Get Referenced Items
$referencedItems = Get-RazlReferencedItems -Connection $sourceConnection -ItemID "{{ItemId}}"
#copy items from source to target
$referencedItems | select -ExpandProperty Id | Copy-RazlItem -source $sourceConnection -target $targetConnection -verbose

In the above snippet, connection to source and target url is made using sitecore url, database name and access guid parameter of the server. Once connection is made, then the referenced item are retrieved using Get-RazlReferencedItems cmdlet function. These items then can be copied to target url using Copy-RazlItem function.
Note: In order to make sure Razl scripting module is imported into powershell, we need to run below command.
import-module [Path to dll]\HedgehogDevelopment.RazlClient.dll -verbose

You can find more details on the cmdlets in Sitecore Razl here.
Hope this helps!!!
